# How to access Keychain of my user from cron?

Tags: keychain, cron

`security list-keychains` print:

```
"/Users/vitaly-zdanevich/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

but the same command from `cron` return:

```
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

from `cron` I tried

```
security default-keychain -s "/Users/vitaly-zdanevich/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db && security list-keychains"
```

but result is the same.

In the help of cli-utility `security` I did not found any other way to explicitly set the path to the db.

Yes I know that Apple says that better way is to use `launchd` instead of `cron`, but I сurious to know - it is possible to manipulate my Keychain from `cron`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the `--help` of the command that you intended to use:

```
$ security delete-generic-password --help
delete-generic-password: illegal option -- -
Usage: delete-generic-password [-a account] [-s service] [options...] [keychain...]
    -a  Match "account" string
    -c  Match "creator" (four-character code)
    -C  Match "type" (four-character code)
    -D  Match "kind" string
    -G  Match "value" string (generic attribute)
    -j  Match "comment" string
    -l  Match "label" string
    -s  Match "service" string
If no keychains are specified to search, the default search list is used.
        Delete a generic password item.
```

so the solution is:

`* * * * * security delete-internet-password -l 'git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' '/Users/vitaly-zdanevich/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db'`

last arg string - is it the path to the Keychain db.

Answer (score 3):

There is one another way of giving cron job the access to our keychains. When you add the password using security add-generic-password -s SERVICE -a USERID -w PASSWORD, you have to first run the script manually to give "always allow" permission to python to access the keychains and then go to your keychains from app launcher and copy that service and password from login.keychians to syste,.keychains as cronjob by default looks into system keychains and not login keychains. This worked for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer, right now it's rather hard to follow/understand. Step-by-step instructions work best.

Comment: this seems to be correct.  cronjobs are looking at some other keychain, not the one where where applications do. having it in "Local Items" was not enough. after copying the item to the System keychain, the cronjob started working. Just out of curiousity, how did you manage to track this down? thanks!